Максимальное число составленное из чисел массива
Дан массив неотрицательных целых чисел nums. Расположите их в таком порядке, чтобы
вместе они образовали максимально возможное число.
Замечание: Результат может быть очень большим числом, поэтому представьте его как
string, а не integer.
Пример 2.1:
Ввод: nums = [10,2]
Вывод: ”210”
Пример 2.2:
Ввод: nums = [3,30,34,5,9]
Вывод: ”9534330”
Пример 2.3:
Ввод: nums = [1]
Вывод: ”1”
Пример 2.4:
Ввод: nums = [10]
Вывод: ”10”

def get_biggest_number(nums):
    # Преобразуем числа в строки и сортируем их в обратном лексикографическом порядке
    nums_str = sorted(map(str, nums), reverse=True)
    # Объединяем отсортированные числа в одну строку
    result = ''.join(nums_str)
    return result

# Примеры использования
print(get_biggest_number([10, 2]))  # Вывод: "210"
print(get_biggest_number([3, 30, 34, 5, 9]))  # Вывод: "9534330"
print(get_biggest_number([1]))  # Вывод: "1"
print(largest_number([10]))  # Вывод: "10"

Выводит:
210
9534303
1
10

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Не понял, чем приведенная get_biggest_number не устраивает?

[9, 8, 95] - что вернёт?

Видимо тем, что получается 9534303 < 9534330

Лексикографическая сортировка не спасает, если одно число является префиксом другого.
Попробуйте использовать такую функцию сравнения - для чисел A и B сравните AB с BA.

Подсказка - для преобразования предложенного компаратора в параметр key= для sorted понадобится такая функция: from functools import cmp_to_key.

Я когда-то сломался на теореме что попарное сравнение достаточно для получения оптимального результата.

@Stanislav Да-да, это вроде логично, но корректность не очевидна
